# Creating figure with two tables stacked and one table to the right

Tags: tables

I want to create a figure like this, with the "Spatial panel data models" table on the right (instead of the left) of the other two stacked tables:

[image]

I have written the following code which produces the following:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c@{\quad}c@{\quad}c}
    Cross-Sectional Data   &   Time Series Data   &   Panel Data   \\
\begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
            $\bm{i}$ & $\bm{t}$ & $\bm{y}$ & $\bm{x}$\\  \hline
               $1$ & $1$ & $y_{1,1}$ & $x_{1,1}$ \\ 
            $1$  & $2$ & $y_{2,1}$ & $x_{2,1}$ \\ 
            $1$ & $3$ & $y_{3,1}$ & $x_{3,1}$ \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
    &   \begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
                $\bm{i}$ & $\bm{t}$ & $\bm{y}$ & $\bm{x}$\\  \hline
               $1$ & $1$ & $y_{1,1}$ & $x_{1,1}$ \\ 
            $1$  & $2$ & $y_{1,2}$ & $x_{1,2}$ \\ 
            $1$ & $3$ & $y_{1,3}$ & $x_{1,3}$ \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
        &   \begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            $\bm{i}$ & $\bm{t}$ & $\bm{y}$ & $\bm{x}$\\  \hline
               $1$ & $1$ & $y_{1,1}$ & $x_{1,1}$ \\ 
            $1$  & $2$ & $y_{1,2}$ & $x_{1,2}$ \\ 
            $1$ & $3$ & $y_{1,3}$ & $x_{1,3}$ \\ 
            $2$ & $1$ & $y_{2,1}$ & $x_{2,1}$ \\ 
            $2$ & $2$ & $y_{2,2}$ & $x_{2,2}$ \\ 
            $2$ & $3$ & $y_{2,3}$ & $x_{2,3}$ \\ 
            $3$ & $1$ & $y_{3,1}$ & $x_{3,1}$ \\ 
            $3$ & $2$ & $y_{3,2}$ & $x_{3,2}$ \\ 
            $3$ & $3$ & $y_{3,3}$ & $x_{3,3}$ \\ \hline
            \end{tabular}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

[image]

Is it possible to *stack* the two tables on the left, with the "Cross-Sectional" table on top and the "Time Series" table below it? Then "Panel Data" would still be on the right?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! The two smaller tables should be on the  right as in the first image, or on the left?

Comment: @Bernard on the left is my idea :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two alternatives using `array` and `subtable` from the `subcaption` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{bm}

\usepackage{booktabs} % only used in second example

\begin{document}
\captionsetup[subtable]{position=above}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{shared caption for all three subtables}
  \begin{subtable}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
    \centering
    \caption{Cross-Sectional Data}
    \(\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
      \hline
      \bm{i} & \bm{t} & \bm{y}  & \bm{x}  \\  
      \hline
      1      & 1      & y_{1,1} & x_{1,1} \\ 
      1      & 2      & y_{2,1} & x_{2,1} \\ 
      1      & 3      & y_{3,1} & x_{3,1} \\ 
      \hline
    \end{array}\)
    \medskip

    \caption{Time Series Data}
    \(\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
         \bm{i} & \bm{t} & \bm{y}  & \bm{x}  \\  
         \hline
         1      & 1      & y_{1,1} & x_{1,1} \\ 
         1      & 2      & y_{1,2} & x_{1,2} \\ 
         1      & 3      & y_{1,3} & x_{1,3} \\ 
         \hline
    \end{array}\)
  \end{subtable}
  \begin{subtable}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
    \centering
    \caption{Panel Data}
    \(\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
      \hline
      \bm{i} & \bm{t} & \bm{y}  & \bm{x}  \\  
      \hline
      1      & 1      & y_{1,1} & x_{1,1} \\ 
      1      & 2      & y_{1,2} & x_{1,2} \\ 
      1      & 3      & y_{1,3} & x_{1,3} \\ 
      2      & 1      & y_{2,1} & x_{2,1} \\ 
      2      & 2      & y_{2,2} & x_{2,2} \\ 
      2      & 3      & y_{2,3} & x_{2,3} \\ 
      3      & 1      & y_{3,1} & x_{3,1} \\ 
      3      & 2      & y_{3,2} & x_{3,2} \\ 
      3      & 3      & y_{3,3} & x_{3,3} \\ 
      \hline
    \end{array}\)
  \end{subtable}
\end{table}


\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{shared caption for all three subtables}
  \begin{subtable}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
    \centering
    \caption{Cross-Sectional Data}
    
    \(\begin{array}{cccc}
      \toprule
      \bm{i} & \bm{t} & \bm{y}  & \bm{x}  \\  
      \midrule
      1      & 1      & y_{1,1} & x_{1,1} \\ 
      1      & 2      & y_{2,1} & x_{2,1} \\ 
      1      & 3      & y_{3,1} & x_{3,1} \\ 
      \bottomrule
    \end{array}\)
    \medskip

    \caption{Time Series Data}
    
    \(\begin{array}{cccc}
      \toprule
      \bm{i} & \bm{t} & \bm{y}  & \bm{x}  \\  
      \midrule
      1      & 1      & y_{1,1} & x_{1,1} \\ 
      1      & 2      & y_{1,2} & x_{1,2} \\ 
      1      & 3      & y_{1,3} & x_{1,3} \\ 
      \bottomrule
    \end{array}\)
  \end{subtable}
  \begin{subtable}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
    \centering
    \caption{Panel Data}
    \(\begin{array}{cccc}
      \toprule
      \bm{i} & \bm{t} & \bm{y}  & \bm{x}  \\  
      \midrule
      1      & 1      & y_{1,1} & x_{1,1} \\ 
      1      & 2      & y_{1,2} & x_{1,2} \\ 
      1      & 3      & y_{1,3} & x_{1,3} \\
      \addlinespace 
      2      & 1      & y_{2,1} & x_{2,1} \\ 
      2      & 2      & y_{2,2} & x_{2,2} \\ 
      2      & 3      & y_{2,3} & x_{2,3} \\
      \addlinespace
      3      & 1      & y_{3,1} & x_{3,1} \\ 
      3      & 2      & y_{3,2} & x_{3,2} \\ 
      3      & 3      & y_{3,3} & x_{3,3} \\ 
      \bottomrule
    \end{array}\)
  \end{subtable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks so much! One thing is that there is now a big gap between the tables on the left and the panel table on the right. Is it possible to reduce this gap between the tables?

Comment: @codemachino: Probably, `\begin{subtable}[t]{0.3\linewidth}` instead of `\begin{subtable}[t]{0.45\linewidth}` results in an output closer to the expected one?

Comment: that would great thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption, subcaption}
\usepackage{ragged2e} 
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\captionsetup{font=bf, position=above, justification=RaggedRight}
\hfill\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
\centering
\subcaptionbox{Cross-sectional data models}{\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
            $\bm{i}$ & $\bm{t}$ & $\bm{y}$ & $\bm{x}$\\ \hline
               $1$ & $1$ & $y_{1,1}$ & $x_{1,1}$ \\
            $1$ & $2$ & $y_{2,1}$ & $x_{2,1}$ \\
            $1$ & $3$ & $y_{3,1}$ & $x_{3,1}$ \\ \hline
\end{tabular}}\bigskip

  \subcaptionbox{Time series data models}{\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
                $\bm{i}$ & $\bm{t}$ & $\bm{y}$ & $\bm{x}$\\ \hline
               $1$ & $1$ & $y_{1,1}$ & $x_{1,1}$ \\
            $1$ & $2$ & $y_{1,2}$ & $x_{1,2}$ \\
            $1$ & $3$ & $y_{1,3}$ & $x_{1,3}$ \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}}
\end{minipage}
\qquad
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
\centering
\subcaptionbox{Spatial panel data models}{\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            $\bm{i}$ & $\bm{t}$ & $\bm{y}$ & $\bm{x}$\\ \hline
               $1$ & $1$ & $y_{1,1}$ & $x_{1,1}$ \\
            $1$ & $2$ & $y_{1,2}$ & $x_{1,2}$ \\
            $1$ & $3$ & $y_{1,3}$ & $x_{1,3}$ \\
            $2$ & $1$ & $y_{2,1}$ & $x_{2,1}$ \\
            $2$ & $2$ & $y_{2,2}$ & $x_{2,2}$ \\
            $2$ & $3$ & $y_{2,3}$ & $x_{2,3}$ \\
            $3$ & $1$ & $y_{3,1}$ & $x_{3,1}$ \\
            $3$ & $2$ & $y_{3,2}$ & $x_{3,2}$ \\
            $3$ & $3$ & $y_{3,3}$ & $x_{3,3}$ \\ \hline
            \end{tabular}}
\end{minipage}
\hfill\mbox{}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]